# Как добавить модуль gearman в php на Winodws?

Tags: php, windows, gearman

Windows хост в нем nginx/apache/php. 
Задача: установить модуль gearman в php

Пробовал установить по данному  ( [мануалу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580956/how-to-configure-or-install-gearman-in-windows-os/50628109#50628109) ) Но как оказалось, ссылка битая.
Думал установить через `go-pear.phar`, но сайт тоже не отдает файлик.

[image: Модуль]

[image: php modules]

1. Каким образом можно установить поддержку модуля?
2. Чем можно заменить gearman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось поднять с помощью данного репозитория  `github.com/brianlmoon/net_gearman`